# Html content is not supporting in excel while exporting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-excel

I want to export html content into excel using javascript library. The code is below.

```
<script src="plugins/JavascriptExcel.js"></script>

  <div id="tbl1"><h1>Table 1</h1>
       <table><tr><td>Product ID</td></tr>
               <tr><td>111</td></tr>    
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="tbl2"><h1>Table 2</h1>
       <table><tr><td>Product ID</td></tr>
               <tr><td>211</td></tr>    
        </table>
    </div>

    <button  onclick="tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['Product1','Product2'], 'document.xls', 'Excel')">Export to Excel</button>
```

The export is not done. If i use only table tag, it will work. But div tag not supported. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: Why can't you add the `tbl1` and `tbl2` ids to the `table` element? Why must/have you got them on a `div`?

Comment: Justinas, Updated the library code in the answer thread.

Comment: I need to add heading and some other details. so that i added div.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var tablesToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?><Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">'
      + '<DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><Author>Axel Richter</Author><Created>{created}</Created></DocumentProperties>'
      + '<Styles>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Currency"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Currency"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '<Style ss:ID="Date"><NumberFormat ss:Format="Medium Date"></NumberFormat></Style>'
      + '</Styles>' 
      + '{worksheets}</Workbook>'
    , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}"><Table>{rows}</Table></Worksheet>'
    , tmplCellXML = '<Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}><Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</Data></Cell>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
      var ctx = "";
      var workbookXML = "";
      var worksheetsXML = "";
      var rowsXML = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
        for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
          rowsXML += '<Row>'
          for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
            var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
            var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
            var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
            dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
            var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
            dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
            ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Currency' || dataStyle=='Date')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                   , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                   , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                   , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                  };
            rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
          }
          rowsXML += '</Row>'
        }
        ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
        worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
        rowsXML = "";
      }

      ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
      workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);

console.log(workbookXML);

      var link = document.createElement("A");
      link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
      link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
      link.target = '_blank';
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  })();
```